# Alarm Clock with multi alarms alghoritm C++

Tags: c++

I've got a simple C++ task - I need to create an alarm app, which triggers alarms a few times.

For example, there is a text file with lines of time in format: hour minutes
I read these into an array.
My idea is that I create an infinite loop which checks what time is it every 60 seconds. Inside this loops, it checks if time == time_array_element_1 or time == time_array_element_2 etc.
And it check every 60 seconds.

Could you guys help me to decide, maybe there is some more optimal way to do it?

Comment: "My idea is that I create an infinite loop which checks what time is it every 60 seconds" - why not create individual timers that expire at the needed times, then go to sleep waiting for a timer to expire? Seems like a more reasonable solution to me.

Comment: Please post the code you have tried so far. SO is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"optimal" strongly depends on what you want to achieve:

- If you just want to have an alarm: use an existing app.
- If you need to implement it on your own program, use a library that provides timer (e.g., [Qt](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html), [boost](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tuttimer2.html), ...)
- If you can't use 3rd party libraries because you're not allowed to (homework?): [build your own](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2018/12/28/timer-cpp/).
- If you don't want or cannot build your own timer library: use that loop approach.

If you want to run the alarm at a particular time every day, you could write an infinite loop that checks whether that time has come. Pseudo-Code:

```
const int alarm_time
const int sleep_time;
while (true) {
   const int current = get_seconds_since_midnight();
   if (current - alarm_time < sleep_time) {
      alarm();
   }
   sleep(sleep_time);
}
```

However, you'd still need to keep this program running all the time.
That's fine if you just want to learn.
But for any other use-case, this task should be handled by the OS (e.g., `cron` on unix).

Comment: "use that loop approach" == use the approach OP has proposed. What aspect have I missed?

Comment: I simply do not know, what if I want that "alarm" run at the same time every day? How could I implement timers then?

Comment: @nextedoff I've updated my answer. As Russ J has mentioned: Stack Overflow works best if you ask a specific question with real code. Write up some code (seriously) and if you have some problem or don't understand something, you can ask. [Good questions start with "Why ...", bad questions start with "could you ..."](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)